# how to query the sharepoint List from outside website by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm totally new on **JavaScript and SharePoint**.
What I am trying to do is to build a website that be able to **connect SharePoint 2010** and query data from it using **JavaScript**. The website I am building is **outside** the SharePoint.

I searched a lot of questions and examples about this topic. But all of these confused me, a very very new programer. So please forgive me if you think I am asking silly questions, but those things really confuse new programer like me. I wish my question could also help others who is as fresh as I am.

Here comes my questions:

*1) what method should I use*

I found a lot of samples teaching how to query the List of SharePoint, e.g. using **Client Object Model**. Does it is applied to my case? I think that is for the SharePoint website programming, am I right? Because based on the sample I see, there is no any URL that link to the SharePoint Server I want to query.

Or using `xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://[my SharePoint Sever]/_vti_bin/search.asmx", true) ...`

*2) what is right URL of the SharePoint Server and its List*

According to my understanding, in my codes, I should first link to the right SharePoint ( or the specific List). so there should be a URL of the SP. I don't think opening the SharePoint List and do copy paste the Address is the right. how to get the right URL and how to alter it (like adding _vti_bin/search.asmx at the end of URL)

*3) what is the right query format*

when I try to right my own query. too many different format of query examples confused me a lot.

```
    soapEnvelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \
...
```

and some looks like this,

```
var soapEnv =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
...
```

*4) any reference should I quote to make my codes work*

should I use Qjuery, XML, or Ajax? What's the connection and how to use them? (sorry about this unclear question, not sure what to ask specifically )

I'm sorta embraced about my un-mature questions. I really need to figure it out somehow....
I will appreciate it a lot if you could give me **a full example** including  and . So I could have a better idea of where is the right place to put my coding.

Thank you so so so much!!!!

Comment: one easy workaround is to make extensive use of sharepoint's RSS features, and then use YQL's rss module to get the feed data into javascript, where mustache et al can make it pretty on your page.

Comment: If you are as new as you say you are, I suggest starting with something easier.

Comment: This is the task I have to take....I really want to know how to link to, or connect to my sharepoint. I assume there should be one or two lines of code covering this job. I got too many ideas I just want a simple one which really works. could you help me out please!

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source library created for Sharepoint 2010, code name Camelot. You can find more information here:

http://camelotjson.codeplex.com/

This is a code sample from the link above:

Javscript:

```
// Build the command
var command =   {
        Type: "SELECT",
        List: "Tasks"
}

var result;

// Send the command using JQUERY
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { command: JSON.stringify(command)},
    url: "/_vti_bin/Camelot.JSONAPI/jsonapi.svc/Items",
    success: function (data) {
        // Decode and store the result in a variable
        result = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        console.log("Successfully executed the command, please check the 'result' variable.");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [SPService](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) or at the library I created: [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/).

I think SharepointPlus is really easy to use. For example if you want to query a list to get the data you'll do something like:

```
$SP().list("Name of your list").get({fields:"First_x0020_Field,OtherField", where:"OtherField = 'something'"}, function(data) {
  for (var i=data.length; i--;) console.log(data[i].getAttribute("First_x0020_Field"))
})
```

Check the SharepointPlus website, it's full of examples. I think it's what you're looking for :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I am wondering how could I link the SharePoint with my on working website. how could I define SP() and point it to my own SP server. could you show me more on this!

Comment: Everything is explained on the website (http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/). Just read it :-)